# Tests don't work in play framework

Tags: playframework

G'Day!

I have a problem. No one tests with database didn't finish successfully.

About project

I have database with data and models which were generated by jpagen. When I try to get Object with data from database in Application.java file it works fine, but when I try to do the same in BaseTest and check object on assertNotNull I have a failure.

List of method of BaseTest:

```
@Test
public void checkUserTable() {
  Users user = Users.find("byUsername", "name_of_user").first();
  assertEquals(2, 1 + 1);   // Ok
  this.assertNotNull(user); // failure
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The test framework points at an in memory database that is created when you start the test suite.  You need to load data using Fixtures.load or create some manually in you test that you can test against.